# Day light saving time and repeating events. What should I store?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

We have the same system as [Google Calendar Events](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?tab=mc&pli=1) now you can create an event and it will notify you at that time.

**PHP cron job will run every 15 minutes, now the settings can be set to send mails every day or weekday or weekend, or every 2nd day of month or weekend. And it can be repeated for few occurrences or forever so we can not store UTC value in the table.I know I can store the UTC for next event and update that column for next event. But I think, there should be a better way to do this then changing UTC on each occurance.**

we have a field which **was storing offset time "-04:00" or "-05:00"** on the basis of timezone you choose.

We had EST, EDT, CST, CDT, PST, PDT, MST, MDT in our drop-down earlier. on the basis of chosen value, we have saved offset in DB which is an incorrect way.

Now when DAYLIGHT SAVING time changes user has to move from EST to EDT or vice versa. Now we want to solve this problem that user does not have to change there settings.

**Want to have a drop-down which has "Eastern, Central, Mountain, Pacific" and want to store the value in DB.**

What value should be stored ? as we do not want to store offset as it will change with DST and it will be an incorrect way.

Another thing how it works. Our servers are in UTC. we have a custom function in MySQL named "isItCorrectTimeToDoThis" which checks that is there any events are present at this time in UTC in time zones. in this function, we are using the CONVERT_TZ function. We have cron job which runs every 15 minutes but a query to get events is in MySql. I hope you guys have understood this part.

**We have Timezone tables installed in our server.**

**WHat should be stored in db table field timezone "EST", "EDT" or "US/Eastern".**

1> I am not able to find what will be the output of CONVERT_TZ(now(),'UTC','EST'); when DST is on.

OR

2> I am not able to find what will be the output of CONVERT_TZ(now(),'UTC','EDT'); when DST is off.

Or

3> CONVERT_TZ(now(),'UTC','US/Eastern')

Which one will handle Daylight savings accurately? That user does not have to change their settings again and again.

Comment: You should absolutely use proper time zone IDs, e.g. America/New_York. US/Eastern isn't too bad (it's still an IANA ID) but it's not as specific. Avoid abbreviations like EST and EDT - a) they're not time zones; b) they're ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the time in UTC and just render the time for the local timezone of the user. This is the best option. The only conversion will be in the UI and that is the only place where you should care for time zones.

Comment: actually, the event can be like every Sunday whole year at 5 PM. so that cannot be an option for us.

Comment: Repeating appointments are indeed not so easy. Let me think a moment about it.

Comment: I know I can store the UTC for next event and update that column for next event. But I think, there should be a better way to do this then doing this.

Comment: I know the Problem, some years ago I had the same issue and I never fixed that bug. However I would store the hours, minutes and timezone where this should be executed. Then I would properbly plan in one "event" the next execution of the "event"/task/whatever with the flowing date, time and timezone which should resolve the problem. However that is not the coolest solution.

Comment: Yes i have stored all those details like  `num_of_occurences` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `minute` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hour` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_of_month` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `repeat_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `repeat_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL .